# Xamarin.iOS push notification tag .NET API / Azure Notification Hub

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, push-notification, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

We're developing a cross platform (Android and iOS) application using Xamarin.Forms. Up to now, we managed to get the app working fine, so it's cool !

We've included some push notifications in our app, using Azure Notification Hub, GCM (for android) and APNS (for iOS). And it works almost fine !

Actually, we just have a last problem : everything is OK for Android, and we can register to push notifications using iOS too, but we can't add some tags to our registrations.

Indeed we need to be able to send a push notification to one user, or one group of users instead of to everyone. To do this, we are doing that in a method of our web api :

```
if (user.DeviceType.Equals("Android"))
{
   registration = new GcmRegistrationDescription(handles.Handle);

}
else
{
   registration = new AppleRegistrationDescription(handles.Handle);
}
registration.Tags = new HashSet<string>();
registration.Tags.Add("usermail:" + user.Email);
registration.Tags.Add("userid:" + user.Id);
registration.Tags.Add("userdevice:" + user.DeviceType);
registration.Tags.Add("usertype:" + tag);
registration.RegistrationId = handles.RegistrationId;
await NotificationHelper.Hub.CreateOrUpdateRegistrationAsync(registration);
```

And for the given Handle, we retrieve it this way in Android :

```
protected override void OnRegistered(Context context, string registrationId)
{
   [...] //the registration id is given in args
}
```

and this way in iOS :

```
public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
{
   [...]

   var DeviceToken = deviceToken.Description;

   if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DeviceToken))
   {
      DeviceToken = DeviceToken.Trim('<').Trim('>');
   }

   UserInformations.Handles.RegistrationId = DeviceToken.Replace(" ", "").ToUpper();

   [...]
}
```

Everything works fine in Android (I'm able to add tags) but I got an error for iOS. The line

> await
>   NotificationHelper.Hub.CreateOrUpdateRegistrationAsync(registration);

is generating an exception, telling me that my registrationId is "not valid anymore". You can notice that I remove spaced in my registrationId for iOS because if I don't, I got another error, telling me that my registrationID contains non-hexadecimal characters.

I don't know what to do to fix this, do I retrievea wrong registrationId in iOS, or is the way to add tags differents for APNS ?

Thanks for your help !

**EDIT :** I noticed that the device token has to be in uppercase. But surprisingly enough, I got the same error. Here are 2 screenshots to help you understand :

[image]
[image]

So you can see that in my registration, what I got in DeviceToken and what I got in RegistrationId are the same... I don't know what to do :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's actually a lot of documentation and thread posts online that tell you to adjust the device token that you get from the iOS method 'RegisteredForRemoteNotifications'. However if you look at the official documentation this is not the correct way of doing it.

Below is a snippet from our 'RegisteredForRemoteNotifications' method, as you can see we don't do anything with the device token, give it a shot and let me know if this solves your problem.

```
            if (oldDeviceToken != null)
            {
                if (oldDeviceToken.ToString() != deviceToken.ToString())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Hub.UnregisterAllAsync(oldDeviceToken, (error) =>
                        {
                            //check for errors in unregistration process.
                            if (error != null)
                            {
                                TestingLogs.ApplicationLog.AppendFile(DateTime.Now.ToString() + "  :  " + "[PNS EXCEPTION] - Exception has been hit! - Message: " + error + " | Source: " + "Unregistering old device token against the notification hub.");
                                //exit out of the code here because we can't keep our hub clean without being able to remove the device from our registration list.
                                return;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                ShouldComplete = true;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    catch (Exception genEx)
                    {
                        TestingLogs.ApplicationLog.AppendFile(DateTime.Now.ToString() + "  :  " + "[PNS EXCEPTION] - Exception has been hit! - Message: " + genEx.Message + " | Source: " + genEx + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Store current device token 
                bool res = await ApplicationSettings.StoreDeviceToken(deviceToken);
            }

            // Check if we need to perform our initial registrations

            if (ShouldComplete)
            {
                NSSet RegisteredTags = await ApplicationSettings.RetrieveUserTags();

                if (RegisteredTags == null)
                {
                    RegisteredTags = new NSSet("AppleDevice");
                }

                //Register the device against the notification hub keeping the details accurate at all times.
                Hub.RegisterNativeAsync(deviceToken, RegisteredTags, (errorCallback) =>
                {
                    if (errorCallback != null)
                    {
                        TestingLogs.ApplicationLog.AppendFile(DateTime.Now.ToString() + "  :  " + "[PNS EXCEPTION] - Exception has been hit! - Message: " + errorCallback + " | Source: " + "Registering device token against the notification hub.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (deviceToken != null)
                        {
                            NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString("Completed", "InitialTagRegistration");
                            NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.Synchronize();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: My decide is already registered, there is no problem with that. My problem is that I need the device token to be able to add tags after it (my device can already receive push notification if I do a "send to all", but now I need to be able to focus only my device and that's why I need the token)

Comment: Well what I do is I store the device token, and when I'm ready to update the tags I call a separate class I created for essentially re-registering the device against the notification hub.

Comment: But in all honesty you need to pass the device token through as is, or it can create an incorrect PNS handle.